# Why is my logical volume not showing in the ansible_lvm variable?

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat, ansible-facts

I have created a playbook to add a volume group (vg.services) and logical volume (lv_new). This results in the specified VG and LV being created as confirmed by the lsblk command:

```
[root@serverb student]# lsblk 
vda 
|---vda1 
|----vda2 
|----vda3 
vdb 
|--**vg.services-lv_new**
```

but when I query the ansible facts I get nothing back:

```
ansible serverb -m setup -a "filter=ansible_lvm"

serverb | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false
```

what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the full playbook and the output of a debug task of `msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"` instead of only the ad-hoc commands [Gathering facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html#gathering-facts) and [`setup` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-filter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [ansible/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py#L819) and [Ansible Issue #17393](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17393)

> "*if running as root and lvm utils are available*"

you need to have high rights like `root` or `become: true`, as well LVM utils installed, otherwise

> "*`gather_facts` silently skips lvm facts if lvm pkg not installed*"