# Ansible: 'debug' task get's me error message 'ansible_lvm' is undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Im trying parted, lvg, lvol and filesystem modules on Ansible.

I have an error with a debug task:

```yaml
- name: lvm debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_lvm }}"
```

The error is:

```json
    fatal: [nfs_server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_lvm' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in ...
```

I thought `ansible_lvm` was gathered during facts gathering since I don't have gathering disabled.

My custom `ansible.cfg` (put in the playbook folder) is as follow:

```ini
[defaults]
host_key_checking= False 
callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks 
pipelining= True
```

Thank you

Comment: Dont know about `ansible_lvm` , Are you disabling the fact gathering from within the playbook? Ie `gather_facts: false`

Comment: @P.... `i dont have gathering disabled` so it looks like the answer is no, gathering is not disabled.

Comment: Are you gathering facts as root? Do you already have lvm enabled on the target vm?

Comment: i have become: true in the playbook. How do i check "already have lvm enabled on the target vm"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [ansible/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py#L819) and [Ansible Issue #17393](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17393)

> "*if running as root and lvm utils are available*"

you need to have high rights like `root` or `become: true`, as well LVM utils installed, otherwise

> "*`gather_facts` silently skips lvm facts if lvm pkg not installed*"

**Similar Q&A**

- [Why is my logical volume not showing in the `ansible_lvm` variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790252/)